# Android questionnaire - saving users submissions to memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am wondering if anybody knows the solution for this: I am creating a questionnaire in Android using radio buttons and I am wondering if there is a solution for Android to remember which radio buttons were clicked. For example I have a register and login and instead of each user having to click through the questionnaire each time how can I make Android remember which buttons were submitted previously. It would be ideal if I could get Android to remember each user submission... any help will be appreciated as I don't even know where to start.

Here is my code for the questionnaire:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_system);
        /*
         * The random generator which generates the data inside each individual
         * string randomly
         */
        randomGenerator = new Random();
        /*
         * The data within each string
         */
        resultsIf1 = new String[] {
                "100% good job",
                "well done" };
        resultsIf2 = new String[] {
                "unlucky",
                        "try again" };

        /*
         * Holding the data for the radio buttons from the xml file
         */
        RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question1);
        gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer1A:
                    ans1 = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.answer1B:
                    ans1 = 2;
                    break;
                }

            }

        });
        RadioGroup nutrition = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question2);
        nutrition.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer2A:
                    ans2 = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.answer2B:
                    ans2 = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });


        btnSubmitQuiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnSubmitQuiz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // result answer 1
                if (ans1 == 1 && ans2 == 1) {

                    displayResult(getRandomResult());

                }
                // result answer 2
                else  {

                    displayResult(getRandomResult2());
                }
            }

            /*
             * displays the results once the submit button is pressed
             */

            private void displayResult(String result) {
                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.system.SHOWRESULT");
                i.putExtra("unique_constant", result);
                startActivity(i);
            }


            public String getRandomResult() {
                return resultsIf1[randomGenerator.nextInt(resultsIf1.length)];
            }

            public String getRandomResult2() {
                return resultsIf2[randomGenerator.nextInt(resultsIf2.length)];
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.system, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several options for permanent storage. I suggest you read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or [Sqlite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) to store the data for later use.